# Problemas con Angular5 el ejecutar el comando ng serve, Errores dentro de ./node_modules/css-loader?

Tags: nodejs, angular5, cmd, angular-cli

tengo un gran problema y espero me puedan ayudar.

Por motivos externos tuve que formatear mi maquina, no sin antes hacer el respectivo respaldo de mis proyecto, hice las instalaciones de nodeJS y luego de angular5 (npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.5).

pero al momento de ejecutar el comando ng serve se levanta el servicio pero luego tengo una serie de errores, los detallo continuación:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./src/assets/sass/material-dashboard.scss
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
 @ ./src/assets/sass/material-dashboard.scss 4:14-221
 @ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css ./node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css ./src/assets/sass/material-dashboard.scss ./src/assets/css/demo.css
ERROR in ./src/app/pages/leccionario/leccionario.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
 @ ./src/app/pages/leccionario/leccionario.component.ts 174:21-60
 @ ./src/app/pages/pages.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
ERROR in ./src/app/pages/planifi-semanal/planifi-semanal.component.scss
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (64)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.7.2
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Web Master\Downloads\Luis Alava 2018-21-12\Atrium\material-dashboard-angular-master\AtriumWeb\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
 @ ./src/app/pages/planifi-semanal/planifi-semanal.component.ts 501:21-64
 @ ./src/app/pages/pages.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

He investigado un poco, pero no he podido dar con la solución, sinceramente no tengo idea que podría ser.

agradezco de antemano el tiempo brindado a mi problema.

Comment: Asi es, instale una version anterio de node y ahora va de maravilla

Comment: Lo pondré como respuesta ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que reinstalaste Node, tus proyectos se quedaron con una versión anterior referenciada de `node-sass`, por lo tanto, la versión que actualmente tienes instalada no es soportada y/o compatible con la versión que tienes en tus proyectos ya que la instalada es una versión superior.

Para solucionarlo ejecuta el comando:

```
npm uninstall node-sass && npm install node-sass
```

Esto quitará las referencias de tu proyecto y posteriormente las actualizará haciéndolas compatibles con tu versión actual de `node-sass`.